# can I use XmlSlurper directly on a w3c.dom.Node object

Tags: groovy, xmlslurper, groovyws

I am experimenting with GroovyWS in the hope of completely replacing Axis2 client code.

One of the Webservice operations I call returns fragments of XML, which I need to turn into Groovy Beans.

I am getting instances of `com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ElementNSImpl` coming out of the WebService call.

I can call `new XmlSlurper().parseText(it as String)` where `it` is the instance of `ElementNSImpl`.

However, of course this writes the Element out to a String before reparsing and slurping it. Is there a way to avoid this unnecessary step ?

Ultimately I want to turn the slurped object into a Groovy Bean; is there a better way to do this. I was wondering about DomToGroovy, but this still gives me a string that I then have run in a Groovy Shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think XmlSlurper supports direct conversions like that, you'd probably have to write something yourself. Maybe if you dig in to the XmlSlurper source there will be a way to do it by extending and adding a new parse() method.  Otherwise, unless you have major performance concerns, I'd say you're on the right track.

Comment: yeah, I'd need to create a GPathResult, but it won't accept the ElementNSImpl instance, so I'd have to convert that into an object it WOULD accept; Perhaps I could write an interface adapter to do that, but its sounding like alot of trouble. Easier just to live with the string conversion ....